# PM2 ecosystem file - writing timestamp to log

Tags: pm2

In the pm2 documentation for [logs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/), it says to use the cli option `--time` to get a timestamp written in the logs.

How do I use this option with the [ecosystem file](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)?

I tried this:

```
module.exports = {
   apps: [
      {
         name: "myapp",
         args: "--time",
         script: "~/path/index.js",
         cwd: "~/path",
         watch: false,
         env: {
            NODE_ENV: "production",
         },
         exp_backoff_restart_delay: 100,
      },
   ],
};
```

and then reloading the ecosystem file with `pm2 startOrReload ~/path/ecosystem.config.js --update-env`, which does successfully reload the configuration, but the timestamp doesn't get written to the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `args: "--time"` in the ecosystem file is ignored. You must specify it using the following directive:

`log_date_format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the timestamp to your logs editing the ecosystem file inside each app object, using `time:true`. In your ecosystem file:

```
module.exports = {
   apps: [
      {
         name: "myapp",
         time: true,
         script: "~/path/index.js",
         cwd: "~/path",
         watch: false,
         env: {
            NODE_ENV: "production",
         },
         exp_backoff_restart_delay: 100,
      },
   ],
};
```